# Standard Deviation - Pert Diagram

Tags: standard-deviation

I am fairly new to Pert Diagrams. I am currently busy with two modules that cover an introduction to Statistics and the other Software Project Management.

I have come across a formula for calculating standard deviation in a pert diagram.

s = (b-a)/ 6

What leaves me curious is the fixed denominator of 6?

I know that following this calculation I am supposed to actually apply the SD formula without dividing by say (N-1) if a sample or N if given the population. I am never comfortable just parrot reading and then doing. I tend to want to know why.

So,

1) Why the denominator 6?

2) When calculating the SD in a pert diagram why am I only finding the square root of the sums of each value squared not dividing by either the total sample or the given population?

See below for more clarity on what I mean re the formulas provided:

[image]

Then below this I have added an example found in the same document:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community.  You might want to add a link to this information.

Comment: @jlimahaverford Thanks! I have added an snippy of the page including this formula as well as the example where the path is calculated too. Let me know if you need anything else?

Comment: @jlimahaverford Doing a bit more reading this might actually make sense. The SD formula seems to be based on the notion that there are approximately 6 SDs between the extreme tails of many statistical distributions. 

It looks more like some sort of a ranking formula as oppose to an SD calc?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the literature that I saw I don't think there's any legitimate sense in which the standard the deviation is (b-a)/6.  The fixed denominator is because the PERT estimate is calculated as a weighted sum of 3 points, repeating one of the points 4 times.

$$
d = \frac{a + 4b + c}{6}.
$$

So in a sense, it seems like they're acting like they have 6 points.  But the numerator on that SD is quite magical to me.

**edit**

Ah, so my denominator guess was completely wrong (I was wondering why it wasn't $\sqrt{6}$ anyway).  So they are "backing into" the notion of standard deviation by saying the distance from optimistic to pessimistic should be $6\sigma$.  Then as seen in the snippet above they're treating each path as a sum of random variables and getting the standard deviation along the path by taking $\sqrt{\sigma_1^2 + \dots + \sigma_k^2}$.  It's more reasonable than I initially gave it credit.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It is a bit strange to me too as I know SD's formula to be quite different. It makes sense re the PERT estimate explanation though.